# I'm writing a book

Tags: novel, self-publishing, romance, profanity, light-novel

I recently quit my job and now I'm bored at home with nothing to do.
So, I decided to write a book.

There is an phone app I can upload it on...

I want the main character to be a woman in her 20s.
What I'm going for is that she is the sole child of a wealthy family, but she wanted to live her life as a normal lower-class civilian, so she moved out.

She wants to live on her own, find work, pay her own rent, so on.

At work she will meet a guy who is of lower-class and one of higher-class like her and will be at odds

What do you think the story should be named?

I would like it to be short and sweet and a little romantic.

Thank you..

Comment: Welcome to Writing.SE! I'm afraid that things like what your story should be called are off-topic here, as there's no objective criteria by which anyone can judge the best answer. We can help you with any specific problems you're having while writing your novel, but the title is up to you.

Comment: You should edit the question so that people can answer it. What are you asking? Be specific.

Comment: As it stands, your question is too specific (only applies to your story). However, finding a good title is a common problem. Check out [How to create a title](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/22079/how-to-create-a-title) and [Can't think of a good name for my story](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/49434/cant-think-of-a-good-name-for-my-story)